# Difference between 硕士英语A班 and 工程硕士英语

Tags: translation, difference

What is the difference between 硕士英语A班 and 工程硕士英语?

I just want to know their exact meaning as Google Translate gives me the same result for both but these words seems to have different meaning.

What I am supposing is that 硕士英语A班 is masters English class and 工程硕士英语 is *not* a class but a whole department or whatever. So I just need to know clear meanings of these two words

Comment: 工程硕士英语, is Engineering Masters English. 硕士英语A班 is Masters English Class A, maybe advanced class?

Comment: My only guess is that, 硕士英语A班 is English Class A for Master's students and 工程硕士英语 is English Class for Engineering Master's Students. We don't really know much about the context, but it's common at universities to run separate English courses for students of different departments to better focus on specific needs (study subject related vocabulary, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

`硕士` means the college degree in modern Chinese, nothing else, unlike the English word Master.

`工程硕士` is Master of Engineering.

`硕士英语` is the English course for a student who is pursuing a master's degree.

`班` is an assembly in which people study and take exams together, usually consisting of 30 or more people.

So to conclude:

`工程硕士英语` is the English course in a college aimed at Chinese M.Eng students who usually have no more than 5000 English words in command. After the course you'll gain an additional 1000 vocabularies as well as a few reading, writing, and translating skills. It's a class focused on basic English skill, not necessarily related to engineering.

`硕士英语A班` is an assembly of M.Eng students taking an English course, this group is labelled as A. There might be B, C, D, etc., but A usually doesn't mean it's better or prioritized; These are just labels.

Answer (score 1):

工程硕士英语 - English for Master Engineering 
硕士英语A班 - English class A for Master (Engineering).

Note that 硕士英语A班 could also be Master (level) English Class A, in a sense of Beginner - Intermediate - Master.  `Master` here is referring to the level not a degree